# How to solve this error? Buy and stock problem allowed only one transaction

Tags: c++

```
class Solution {
public:
    int maxProfit(vector<int>& prices) {      
        int buy;
        int sell;
        buy = sell = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < prices.size(); i++)
        {
            if(prices[buy] > prices[i] && (i != prices.size() - 1))
            {
                buy = i;
                sell = i;
            }
            else if(prices[sell] < prices[i])
                sell = i;
        }
        
        return prices[sell] - prices[buy];
    }
};
```

The error:

```
Line 924: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'int' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/8/../../../../include/c++/8/bits/stl_vector.h:933:9
```

Comment: What would happen to your code if `prices.size()` equals zero?

Comment: i got your point, thank you!